# Databases presenting Mandatory Access Control Multilevel Security

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, security

I'm looking for fine grained (row and column level) access control in databases. In other words, I'm looking for **mandatory access control (MAC)**, security policies that classify data and users based on security classes (something like the [Bell-LaPadula model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell-La_Padula_model)).

Oracle has a product, *Oracle Label Security* that implements powerful multilevel security at row level on Oracle DBMSs. Unfortunately, I was unable to find similar solutions in other databases as MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

SE-PostgreSQL (http://code.google.com/p/sepgsql/) appears to be attempting to do exactly this. It controls database access via SE Linux policies. 
I'm not sure how "stable" it is, or if it's ready for production databases, but it seems be the most anyone has done toward implementing fine-grained access control on the open-source databases.

+1 quite interesting question.